# Trying to append to a file, (my code seems to keep creating a new file)

Tags: java

I', trying to write a program that sample data then adds it to a file.  Right noe the code seems to creat a new file each time.  The file only contains the last data I wrote to it, and not the data before that.

code:

```
static void run2() {

    cGlobals.mBitTrex.FillMarketData();

    for(int ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
    {
        for(int i=0; cGlobals.mBitTrex.data[i]!=null; i++ )
    {
        cTicker prices=cGlobals.mBitTrex.data[i];
        String s="";
        s=Double.toString(prices.last)+","+Double.toString(prices.bid)+","+Double.toString(prices.ask);
        WriteFile( "gra"+prices.name+".txt", s);
    }
         System.out.println("Next Graph Point-" );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

// This function seems to keep creating a new file, data does not get added to
// the old informtion n the file, the file will contain just data

```
static void WriteFile( String path, String data) {

try {


    File file =new File(path);

    //if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if(!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();


    //true = append file
    FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName());
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.write("\r" );
        bufferWritter.write("\n" );


        bufferWritter.close();

}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: [Read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29). Your comment `//true = append file` shows that you had that before (I assume).

Comment: 1. `new FileWriter(file.getName()` should be `new FileWriter(file)`, otherwise you are throwing away part of `path.` 2. Don't test `file.exists()` or call `file.createNewFile()`. `new FileWriter(...)` already does that, in the operating system. You're just duplicating work and in fact causing the file to be created twice.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `FileWriter` to append mode by adding `true` after the filename:

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
```